# MongoDB aggregation field with underscore

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a field `_type_` in my documents like this:

```
{
    "name" : "0",
    "_type_" : "product"
}
```

I need to do aggregation on that field:

```
db.readImport.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "$_type_": "product"
        }
    },
    ...
]);
```

When the field would not have underscores it would work but this way I get

```
unknown top level operator: $_type_
```

- how can I access the field `_type_` with `$` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$` for $match stage:

```
db.readImport.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "_type_": "product" }
    },
    ...
]);
```

because $match stage accepts simple query as parameter. Other aggregation stages, such as $group, accept expressions. Expressions use [filed path](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/glossary/#term-field-path) to access fields of input documents.